# OnBeforeUnload warning except for when refreshing the current page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Does anybody know if it is possible to check what page a user is leaving for when the OnBeforeUnload event fires. I want to notify users when they are actually leaving the current page but not when they are just reloading it.

Comment: Best you can achieve is to avoid the warning when user click some link in your page or press some button or submits a form - if relevant let me know and I'll give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nooo, that would be a huge security hole if the browser told the webpage where the user was going.  I suppose it wouldn't be a problem if the webpage were told only exactly what it is you want to know -- this is/is not a reload -- but nope, I can't see how you could figure that out.